# NSRegularExpression - Every Character except a specific one

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

i want to use a RegularExpression and I want to make a rule in it that every character expect of specific one is allowed (In my case The < and >).
I know (.*) to allow every character.
So how can I limit the . without listing all characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a negated character set. For example, in your case, you can use [`[^<>]*`](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5B%5E%3C%3E%5D%2a&input=x%5E2%20%2b%20y%5E2%20%3E%20z%5E2).

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried ^[><]  Use this to skip characters in  square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
  #define VALIDATION @"[<>a-zA-Z\\d]"
    NSPredicate *NameValidation = [ NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", VALIDATION];
    int retVal  = [NameValidation evaluateWithObject:inPasskey];
```

Hope, this will you..